# Publishing from Author logins not performing for all fields

Tags: publishing, item-name

Publishing from my author/editor logins is not copying the entire item. For e.g. when I publish my item with its name and displayname changed, changes in web database are showing a renamed displayname but not the name. This is messing my item paths. Tried smart publishing and full publishing including related items and subitems.

Found similar post for earlier version on https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/5773

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I applied the hotfix provided for earlier versions and it has fixed the above issue. Now the complete item gets published even for Editors.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/136794